# windows phone startActivityForResult (start external app and get result)

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have WP app AppServiceWorker for download/sync data with specific http protocol. Now I create WP app AppDataManagment. This app must download data from many place. And must work with specific http protocol as AppServiceWorker.

I want start AppServiceWorker from AppDataManagment. AppServiceWorker download data and return to AppDataManagment.

In android

```js
Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");                      
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Can I use "URI association"?

Or create class library and use i use in both app?

Comment: Here is no easy way to share data between apps. Are you sure that you need separate apps for this task?

Comment: There are any way to share data between apps? I`m sure. There are many options for work with specific http protocol. AppDataManagment not necessarily work with if AppServiceWorker not installed

Comment: You can only share data when launching an application, or the data needs to be stored in a central location accessible by both applications (like on a DB server for example). A class library would allow you to share code.